# IIS 7.5 sub-folder 403 - Forbidden Error - Angular project

Tags: angular, iis, iis-7.5

I am using IIS 7.5 to host an Angular site made with the CLI. The site loads fine, but I am noticing that my `/assets/images` folder is getting a 403 forbidden error. 
Both the `assets` and `images` folders have `Anonymous Authentication` set to `Enabled` for the `Application Pool Identity`.

I previously had the two folders as virtual directories, but it was still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was in my template files I just needed to reference it as `./assets/images/image.png` and not as an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```